# pre populated database не работает при повышения версии базы данных

Tags: android, android-room

У меня проект, в котором я использую готовую базу данных.

```
 database =
            Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "my_database.db")
                .createFromAsset("databases/my_database.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
```

всё работает, но когда я изменяю базу данных, мне приходится повышать версию бд. А когда я повышаю версию бд пре-популяция не работает (бд как будто просто пустая).Вопрос:
Что я могу сделать в такой ситуации?

Comment: По идее вот эта строка вам базу трёт `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`

Comment: я тоже думаю что .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() все портит. Но тут другой вопрос в коде не описаны миграции, то в чем смысл вообще поднимать версию базы.